# javascript shopping cart need support

Tags: javascript, html, shopping-cart

Hi I am fairly new to javascript and im creating a simple shopping cart in javascript for a website im trying to calculate the subtotal by multiply quantity **(#qty)** by Price **(#price)** to get the display in the the **subtotal** and add all subtotal to calculated the Total(Please help me):-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#qty").onChange(function(){
$("#subtotal").val(parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt($("#price").val()));
});
```

});

Comment: Do you want that someone should code for you now??

Comment: Yes please can you help me.

Comment: man you only need some logics to be jotted down on to the file. No one is going to code for you here, try taking help where you are stuck on to some logics.

Comment: This is not how SO works, you have to post little code snippets which describes your problem, instead of posting the whole code.
You did not even explained what you don't understand.

Comment: im having problem summing the subtotal using qty and price which are displayed as text and add all subtotal to calculate Total, I've tried different methods but none are working

Answer (score 0):

You can use change keyup and paste event to calculate your subtotal

```
$("#qty").on('change keyup paste', function() {
    $("#subtotal").val(parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt($("#price").val()));
});
```

check the working fiddle
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmte0jwv/)

Comment: Hi Tanya thanks very much for the reply but at the moment nothing is changing i think the problem might be within the html.

Comment: hey! check the mentioned fiddle in above answer

Comment: Thank you very much had to change .val to .text as my fields weren't input text but html text.